# estimateGas - how does it work when there's an internal call?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I've read the following:

> The catch about gas estimation is that the node will try out your tx
> with different gas values, and return the lowest one for which your tx
> doesn't fail. But it only looks at your tx, not at any of the internal
> call it makes. This means that if the contract code you're calling has
> a try/catch that causes it not to revert if an internal call does, you
> can get a gas estimation that would be enough for the caller contract,
> but not for the callee.

Question 1) so, If I have `contractA` and `contractB`, does this mean that even If I don't have try/catch block at all in `contractA`  and the `contratA` calls `contractB`, `estimateGas` will still return the gas estimation for only `contractA` and won't include the gas estimation for `contractB`'s function ?

Question 2)  Could you better explain if possible the snippet I copied  above ?